# Newcommand of ifthenelse, missing the first characters of the text

Tags: latex

My little example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{{\xx}}[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{
        \underline{\makebox[20mm][c]{}}
    }{\underline{\makebox[#1mm][c]{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\xx world peace

\xx[30] world peace

\xx{hello world} world peace

\xx[30]{hello world} world peace

\end{document}
```

There are something wrong with `\xx world peace` and `\xx[30] world peace`, with corresponding first characters of the word missing or wrong-placed. Well, we can fix this by replace them with `\xx{} world peace` and `\xx[30]{} world peace`. However, how can it be fixed if I insist using `\xx world peace` and `\xx[30] world peace`?

Comment: Have a look at the functionalities offered by the `xparse` package